# How do I create a new heartbeat message variable?

Tags: theming

There is a heartbeat message template like the following, which gets filled in whenever a user joins a group.

'!username joined the group !group_title'

Is it possible to create a new variable or change the value that is plugged in for a heartbeat variable?

I'm trying to do something like this to show the user's fullname:

'!userfullname joined the group !group_title'

Thanks,
Greg